# How do I connect these faces without creating bevel problems?

Tags: vertices, faces, geometry, bevel, artifacts

[image: What my object looks like atm]I am currently in the process of modelling my headphones (DT770s) and I ran into a problem that I cannot seem to find a fix for. I have one Vertex where five faces with different orientations connect and if i put a bevel on my object there are weird overlaps in the bevel like you would get with double vertices around that Vertex. I tried connecting them differently and remodeling the object outright, with no success.

Comment: are you sure you don't have flipped normals?

Comment: The one edge going towards the background is partly visible, partly not - this definitely looks like overlapping geometry and / or flipped normals or other mesh problems. That's what I'd say from the screenshot, to verify this I would need the mesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. It seems to have been a normals issue, as suspected by Gordon and Moonboots. I recalculated the outside and did some minor adjustments on the topology and now everything works as intended. Thank you very much for the advice.[image]